# How to get back Chinese Speech after upgrading to Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, speech

After upgrading to Mojave, I cannot use Chinese Speech any more. If I go to

```
Preference → Accessibility → Speech
```

and choose any of the Chinese Speech (Mandarin, Cantonese), for Ting-Ting, Sin-ji, Mei-Jia, it just gives me a "DONG" sound and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with the upgrade to Mojave.  I then first removed all the speeches in Chinese inside of System Preferences, and then rebooted the Mac, and then added the speeches back.  After the download, this fixed the problem.